# How to adjust font size of text in a UIButton to fit the height programmatically in Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, uibutton

I have a button, and set its frame & title:

```
let button = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.System) as UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
button.setTitle("Shuffle", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

I have been using the below to change the width of text in the UIButton:

```
button.titleLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

This does adjust the font size to the width, but not the height of the button. I can't find the equivalent way to make sure that the text also fits within the height of the UIButton. I also tried the below, but it didn't work for me:

```
button.titleLabel?.drawTextInRect(button.frame)
```

Comment: Have a look at the `baslineAdjustment` property: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/baselineAdjustment

Comment: I found the following worked in my case: button.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment =    UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters

Comment: Great. Have added an aswer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the [`baselineAdjustment`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/baselineAdjustment) property of `UILabel`:

It can be used with a UIButton as follows:

```
button.titleLabel?.baselineAdjustment = UIBaselineAdjustment.AlignCenters
```

Comment: This totally saved my ass. I love you.